# Axios post fails with status code 500 in Laravel and Vue.js

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

Hey guys I'm new to this and couldn't fix this myself.
When I try to store some names in `parent` table in my database, I receive a 500 status code.
Here is my Laravel code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use http\Exception;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use app\Models\category;
use app\Models\parents;
class categorycontroller extends Controller
{
    .
    .
    .
    protected $parent = [];
    public function Mcategory(Request $request)
    {
       //throw new Exception();
       $parent=new parents();
       $parent->name=$request->name;
       $parent->save();
       return $parent;
    }
}
```

and here is my axios post method in Vue.js

```
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data:{
        name:""
    },
    created:function(){

    },
    methods:{
        Mcategory:function(){
                axios.post('/admin/Mcategory',{
                    name:this.name
                    //name:"salam"
                }).then(response=>{
                    console.log(this.name);
                },response=>{
                    this.error=1;
                    console.log('error');
                });
        }
    }
});
```

Also, I couldn't find how to trace the error using `.catch(...)`; any tips on how to trace the error and see it's cause would be appreciated.

Comment: A 500 error is a generic error message and covers pretty much every single thing that can go wrong with a PHP script. Check your server error logs and your Laravel logs (in `/storage/logs`) to find out the exact error message.

Comment: You can look in the log file at `storage/logs/laravel.log` the most recent entry will be towards the end of file. Look in the stack trace and identify which line is causing the error - or you can post the stack trace in your question for suggestions

Comment: One apparent cause visible in your code above is namespaces in use statements `use 
 app\Models\category; use app\Models\parents;` should have been `use App\Models\category;` and `use App\Models\parents;` the folder is app but is mapped to namespace `App` with a capital A

Comment: Thank you guys! changed my code as @Donkarnash said and checked the log, there was a problem with my database.

Answer (score 0):

bind your code in try catch block like this and see the network tab what you get in the response...then you can search for the error or give us a snippet so that we can help you

```
try {
                $parent=new parents();
           $parent->name=$request->name;
           $parent->save();
                return response()->json(['success' => $parent], 200);
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                return response()->json(['error' => $e->getMessage()], 503);
            }
```